# Electron - blank page when video enters full screen mode

Tags: node.js, video, electron, fullscreen, electron-builder

I have an electron app that contains a video player, I am using  HTML5  tag to play the videos
when the video's fullscreen button is clicked, a blank screen is displayed

[image: screenshot]

here is how my pckage.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "1.4.4",
  "description": " xxxx application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "electron:start": "electron ./",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3"
  },
  "win": {
    "iconUrl": "icon.ico"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/electron": "^1.2.0",
    "big-json": "^3.0.0",
    "electron-is-dev": "^0.3.0",
    "electron-log": "^3.0.8",
    "electron-unhandled": "^3.0.0",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.9",
    "knex": "^0.19.4",
    "parse-json": "^5.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-progress": "^3.0.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.1.0",
    "yieldable-json": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.4",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "electron"
  ],
   "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Nothing in the logs?

Comment: @Slbox unfortunately not